# Random forest number of trees and cross validation

Tags: machine-learning, bigdata, data-science

I'm using repeated cross validation in random forest as follows:
    k=10
    repeat =3
I have set my random forest to grow a thousand trees and use 6 variables for splitting at each node:
    ntree = 1000 
    mtry = 6
I need to understand does each iteration of the cross validation build 1000 trees:
   fold 1.rep1: mtry = 6    (does this iteration build 1000 trees??)
   fold 2.rep2: mtry = 6    (does this iteration build 1000 trees??)

or the total of all cross validation iterations sums to 1000 trees?

Comment: Cross validation takes the classifier you constructed and runs it several times. therefore it takes a forest of 1000 trees each time.

Answer (score 0):

Every fold of every repetition trains 1000 trees.